# Does S3 filtering allow wildcards for prefixes and suffixes in Lambda function triggering?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have the following bucket configuration in my CloudFormation template:

```
DummyBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  DependsOn:
  - DummyBucketPermission
  - DummyImportFunction
  Properties:
    BucketName:
      ...
    BucketEncryption:
      ...
    NotificationConfiguration:
      LambdaConfigurations:
      - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
        Function:
          Fn::GetAtt: DummyFunction.Arn
        Filter:
          S3Key:
            Rules:
            - Name: prefix
              Value: queued/
            - Name: suffix
              Value: .csv
```

After I deploy my stack, I create a `queued` directory in that bucket and observation that uploading 'test1.csv' into `queued` triggers the notification, but creating another directory inside `queued` (e.g. `a`) and uploading 'test2.csv' to `queued/a` does not trigger it. Is there any way that CloudFormation allows the use of wildcards in prefixes and suffixes to support nested directories?

Comment: A rule with prefix `queued/` and suffix `.csv` matches `queued/*.csv` `queued/*/*.csv` `queued/*/*/*.csv` ad infinitum.  The actual question is how it's possible for `queued/a/test2.csv` **not** to have triggered the function.  This should have worked.